# How to retrieve a string from UITextField use it for a Parse query with PFQuery and then load to a Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I would like to create a basic search function without search bar display. I've created a UITextfield for the input text, a search button for the PFQuery and a table view where i want to display the results of the search. (User types a name to into the textfield, hit enter and if there is a match the results will appear in the table view.)

I tried to use this code for the [query](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-i-find-a-parse-user-by-pfusers-username-property) without any success. The xcode says "Unused variable 'user'" and the same with the *searchResult*. I don't understand why are these variables unused.

It's from the log:

*A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.*

**my .m file:**

```
@interface TestViewController () 

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// mainArray = [query findObjects];
mainArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user", nil];

}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [mainArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"thisCell"];
cell.textLabel.text = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender {
  NSString *searchResult = [self.searchField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:@"searchResult"];
PFUser *user = (PFUser *)[query getFirstObject];
// NSArray *searchedItem = [query findObjects];

}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
@end
```

**.h file:**

```
@interface TestViewController :UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{

    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    NSArray *mainArray;
    NSString *searchResult;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchField;
- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: What's not to understand? You create and assign those two variables but they aren't used after that. Hence the warnings.

Comment: Also the Parse query is being run on the main thread, which is generally something you want to avoid unless absolutely necessary, hence that log.  Parse queries have built in methods that use blocks such as findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. Check out their documentation/examples.

Comment: @shim is correct.  Your app will almost certainly get rejected if you leave that.

Comment: Rejected? No, Apple doesn't check for things like that when reviewing apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no errors. "Unused" is a warning that means you're not using the "user" variable for anything. Sure, you're giving it a value, but you're not using that value afterwards. A simple call to NSLog displaying something will remove that warning:

```
NSLog(@"Username: %@", user[@"username"];
```

Also, as shim stated, the warning about a long-running Parse operation is because you use

```
[query getFirstObject];
```

which is run on the main thread. To get rid of that warning, you use one of the background functions, like

```
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
  if (object) {
    PFUser *user = (PFUser *)object;
    NSLog(@"Username: %@", user[@"username"]);
  }
}];
```

**UPDATE**

Edit the function like this (no quotes for searchResult):

```
- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender {
  NSString *searchResult = [self.searchField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
  PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
  [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:searchResult];
  PFUser *user = (PFUser *)[query getFirstObject];
  // NSArray *searchedItem = [query findObjects];
}
```

Comment: I've changed the _[query getFirstObject]_ to the _getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock_, it removed the warning, but the searchResult variable is still unused and i think this is the reason why the query can't find anything. I want to find the user that's username was entered into the _searchField_. I've created a property for searchField and the NSString to hold it's content. Do you have any idea what did i wrong?

Comment: Super! I also changed the NSArray to mutable and works fine. Thnx